# Best practices for using modules across project

Tags: java, architecture

If I have a project layout in a fashion similar to below:

```
Project
 |_ DataTier
    |_ src
       |_ com.xyz.DT
          |_ DataResource.java
 |_ EmailServ
    |_ src
       |_ com.xyz.Email
          |_ Email.java
 |_ SchedulerServ
    |_ src
       |_ com.xyz.SchedulerServ
          |_ Scheduler.java
```

If I need to access an Email job from the Scheduler,
what is the best practice for communication between tiers?

Is it ok for me to put an Email dependency into the Scheduler via a POM.xml?

Comment: Why should it not be ok? If scheduler needs email, make email a dependency of scheduler.

Comment: Maybe i should add more context. Im working on fixing code that was developed a few years ago and the legacy devs no longer work on this team. If they require a dependency from another tier, they use a PostRequest method and pass a url with the method mapped to it. Those classes that are depended on use managed beans to be able to fulfill this request. Im a jr dev so when i saw this wasnt sure if i was missing something and became unsure of the best practice.

Comment: I think this forum is more suitable for this question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: You may want to ask about the best practice **in your company**.

Comment: @dan1st would you believe me if I told you that this forum wasnt my first resort........

Comment: I believe you. What did the people in your company say?